# xetex – Text goes beyond the margin

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, geometry, polyglossia

I am using geometry to set my margins, polyglossia for hyphenation patterns and xetex for compiling. Here is my code

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[xetex]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    margin=15mm,
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\tolerance=100
\setmainfont{Roboto-Light}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\enablehyphenation
\righthyphenmin=100
\hyphenpenalty=50
\begin{document}
Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке соответствующий условий активизации. Таким образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности требуют определения и уточнения позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Равным образом консультация с широким активом позволяет оценить значение систем массового участия. Разнообразный и богатый опыт консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

Повседневная практика показывает, что сложившаяся структура организации представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки дальнейших направлений развития. Задача организации, в особенности же рамки и место обучения кадров играет важную роль в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

Разнообразный и богатый опыт новая модель организационной деятельности играет важную роль в формировании системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Равным образом сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.

Товарищи! рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет оценить значение дальнейших направлений развития. Разнообразный и богатый опыт дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации дальнейших направлений развития.
\end{document}
```

After compiling to pdf it is visible that text is going beyond the page width. I tried changing tolerance/hyphenpenalty but that does not seem to have any effect. What am I doing wrong?[image: doc]

Comment: The document as posted produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kSXm.png) in texlive 2018 xe;atex) there is one over-full line, if you add `\sloppy` after `\begin{document}` there are no overfull lines, and the output is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kSXm.png)